# Request to one API endpoint causes 500 response; other API endpoints work

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to accept origin as http://192.168.1.35:4200 and I created the CORSFilter like this in the springboot:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

public CORSFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.1.35:4200");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Auth_Token");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

And I created the request like this to call the spring rest api from angular:

```
 getAllUsers(): void {
    this.accessToken = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')).access_token;
    this.httpClient.get<User[]>(`${BASE_URL}/fam-users/user?access_token=${this.accessToken}`, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
        this.dataChange.next(data);
    },
        (err: ApiError) => {
            this.snackBar.openSnackBar(err.error.message, 'close', 'red-snackbar');
        });

}
```

When I send request, It says that

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.35:8080/fam-users/user?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NTAwNDMwODMsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiRkFfQU1FTkQiLCJGQV9ORVciXSwianRpIjoiOWViMzZjNzAtOGUwOS00YzViLWI0OWQtNDNmZTRhOTkzNDgzIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50Iiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVhZCIsIndyaXRlIiwidHJ1c3QiXX0.IETZOJE8tIqNc249HmTcJHuZpZFY1TP4PLcbqUOF3qc' from origin 'http://192.168.1.35:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But all other requests from 'http://192.168.1.35:4200' are working fine.

Can Someone guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response when you get that error message?

Comment: @sideshowbarker It's 500

Comment: So yeah that 500 error is the problem you need to fix. Some internal server failure happened. Check the server logs to see what messages are getting logged there the lead to the server to respond with that 500.

Comment: @sideshowbarker serverside has no failure and all are successfully finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  @CrossOrigin annotation in spring boo, for example:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

for more please have a [look](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)